# my php form send empty emails from all the require fields

Tags: php, forms, function, email, contacts

I have a problem, I have a php form and it send emails correctly so the email function() is correct. I don't know what else can be, I think the variables are not been taking when the user enters the information. Here I have my .php form

Thanks in advance

```
                <script type="text/javascript">
            <!--
            function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
              var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
                var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
                if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
            }
            function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
              var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
            }
            function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
              var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
                d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
              if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
              for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
              if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
            }

            function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
              var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
               if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
            }
            //-->
            </script>
            <body onLoad="MM_preloadImages('botones/inicio2.png','botones/nosotros2.png','botones/lindustrial.png','botones/lcomercial2.png','botones/divisiones2.png','botones/contato2.png')">
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <div id="container">
              <div id="header">
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <table width="100" border="0">
                  <tr>
                    <th width="25%" scope="col"><p></p>
                      <p><a href="index.html"><img src="img/imagenes/logo.png" alt="" width="288" height="175" /></a></p></th>
                    <th width="67%" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
                    <th width="4%" scope="col"><img src="iconofono.png" alt="" width="652" height="179" /></th>
                  </tr>
                </table>
                <h1><img src="huincha.png" alt="" width="996" height="1" /></h1>
                <table width="650" border="0" align="center">
                  <tr> </tr>
                </table>
              </div>
              <table width="970" border="0">
                <tr>
                  <td width="18%"><a href="index.html" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Imagen20','','botones/inicio2.png',1)"><img src="botones/inicio.png" alt="" name="Imagen20" width="138" height="23" border="0" id="Imagen20" /></a></td>
                  <td width="13%"><a href="nosotros.html" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Imagen21','','botones/nosotros2.png',1)"><img src="botones/nosotros.png" alt="" name="Imagen21" width="138" height="23" border="0" id="Imagen21" /></a><a href="#" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Imagen14','','botones/nosotros2.png',0)">
                    <!-- Start dwuser_maximenu -->
                    <!-- Do not remove the line below!!!  It is required for the DWUser MaxiMenu. -->
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/maximenu.js"></script>
                    </a>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    // <![CDATA[
                    if (!MaxiMenu) { MaxiMenu = function(){}; alert('To use the MaxiMenu, you must upload the maximenu_files/maximenu.js file, and have a properly defined reference to it in your HTML.');};
                    MaxiMenu({normal_width:'600',redirect:'',holder_id:'dwuser_maximenu_0',expanded_width:'700',normal_height:'40',expanded_height:'500'});
                    // ]]>
                      </script>
                    <noscript>
                    </noscript>
                    <!-- End dwuser_maximenu --></td>
                  <td width="12%"><a href="industrial.html" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Imagen15','','botones/lindustrial.png',1)"><img src="botones/lindustrial2.png" alt="" name="Imagen15" width="138" height="23" border="0" id="Imagen15" /></a></td>
                  <td width="19%"><a href="comercial.html" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Imagen16','','botones/lcomercial2.png',1)"><img src="botones/lcomercial.png" alt="" name="Imagen16" width="138" height="23" border="0" id="Imagen16" /></a></td>
                  <td width="18%"><a href="divisiones.html" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Imagen17','','botones/divisiones2.png',1)"><img src="botones/divisiones.png" alt="" name="Imagen17" width="138" height="23" border="0" id="Imagen17" /></a></td>
                  <td width="20%"><a href="contacto.html" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Imagen19','','botones/contato2.png',1)"><img src="botones/contacto.png" alt="" name="Imagen19" width="138" height="23" border="0" id="Imagen19" /></a></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <p>
                <!-- Este elemento de eliminación siempre debe ir inmediatamente después del div #mainContent para forzar al div #container a que contenga todos los elementos flotantes hijos -->
                <?php
            //Importamos las variables del formulario de contacto

            @$nombre = addslashes($_POST['nombre']);
            @$rut = addslashes($_POST['rut'].'-'.$_POST['dv']);
            @$email = addslashes($_POST['email']);
            @$fono = addslashes($_POST['fono']);
            @$mensaje = addslashes($_POST['mensaje']);



            //Preparamos el mensaje de contacto
            $cabeceras = "From: $email\n" //La persona que envia el correo
             . "Reply-To: $email\n";
            $asunto = "Mensaje desde la Web pesaje.cl"; //asunto aparecera en la bandeja del servidor de correo
            //$email_to = "test@test.com"; //cambiar por tu email
            $email_to = "aarancibia2009@gmail.com"; //cambiar por tu email
            $contenido = "$formulario"
            . "\n"
            . "Nombre: $nombre\n"
            . "Rut: $rut\n"
            . "Email: $email\n"
            . "Fono: $fono\n"
            . "Mensaje: $mensaje\n"
            . "\n";
            //Enviamos el mensaje y comprobamos el resultado
            if (@mail($email_to, $asunto ,$contenido ,$cabeceras )) {

            //Si el mensaje se envía muestra una confirmación
            die("Gracias, su mensaje se envio correctamente, nos pondremos en contacto a la brevedad con Usted.");
            }else{
            //Si el mensaje no se envía muestra el mensaje de error
            die("Error: Su información no pudo ser enviada, intente más tarde");
            }
            ?>
              </p>
              <p><img src="huincha.png" alt="" width="996" height="1" /><br class="clearfloat" />
              </p>
              <div id="footer">
                <table width="101%" border="0">
                  <tr>
                    <th width="57%" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
                    <th width="35%" class="pie" scope="col"><span class="pie11">Las Heras 097, Curico, Fono: 075/317111</span></th>
                    <th width="8%" scope="col"><img src="pie.png" alt="" width="52" height="33" /></th>
                  </tr>
                </table>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <!-- end #footer -->
              </div>
              <!-- end #container -->
            </div>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Comment: Get rid of all the `@`.

Comment: Except for the one in the email address - just thought I'd mention!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. you said to get rid of the @ in this pleace? @$nombre = addslashes($_POST['nombre']);
            @$rut = addslashes($_POST['rut'].'-'.$_POST['dv']);
            @$email = addslashes($_POST['email']);
            @$fono = addslashes($_POST['fono']);
            @$mensaje = addslashes($_POST['mensaje']);

Comment: Yes. And from in front of the `mail()` function, too.

Comment: hi, ok I have it removed, do you mind explain me why is this? thanks again